# Querying a collection in .NET 3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

I am working on an application targeted at .NET framework 3.0 . I have a requirement of querying a list of objects.LINQ cant be used unfortunately as it is 3.0 . Can anyone provide an effective way to do so?

Comment: foreach? or any of the other looping mechanisms?

Comment: What have you tried? What kinda object are you taking about? You know we can see your code

Comment: i have two methods in mind one can be the obvious method of loops or objects can be serialized to xml and queried through xpath , but both doesnt seem to be much effective.Is there any feature of collections that can be utilised here. I have not started with the code yet,first i want to finalise the approach.